# Excel date conversion and grouping

Tags: excel

I have 20 years of week dates and their corresponding values. The date format is yyyy-mm-dd (the data is not in date format but just in this format on excel), and each of this has a corresponding value. I need to find daily, weekly, monthly, yearly averages. Since the data is too big and I can't find them manually. 
Is there any way I can first convert this non-western type of date into some date types and then use some excel functions to do my calculation?

Thanks

Comment: You can try `DATEVALUE` although it may balk at the non standard format.  If that's the case, you can build a `=DATE(YEAR, MONTH, DAY)` using a number of calls to `MID` to get the year, month, and day.  If the format always includes MM and DD, then `MID` should work very well.

Answer (score 0):

If `yyyy-mm-dd` is text you should be able to convert to number by entering `1` somewhere and copying that, then selecting all the text to be converted and Paste, Paste Special..., check Multiply, OK.

You don't mention what you are averaging (a total divided by number of days/weeks/months/years involved?) but if just counting by day/week/month/year then a PivotTable should be very useful (dates for ROWS and Sum of values for VALUES), with grouping of rows to suit.